# How do I get items with the most occurrences of a property value?

Tags: elm

I have a list of records that can occasionally have the same property value of other records within the list.

I want to identify the top most occurrences of a property value.

Such a record can be the following:

```
type alias Topic =
    { name : String }
```

I believe that in order to accomplish this, I need to use [List.groupBy](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/circuithub/elm-list-extra/3.10.0/List-Extra#groupBy).

As a result, I tried the following:

```
topicGroups =
        |> someTopics
        |> List.map .name
        |> groupWhile (\name1 name2 -> name1 == name2)

orderedTopics =
    topicGroups
        |> List.sortBy List.length
        |> List.reverse
        |> List.concat
        |> uniqueBy toString
        |> List.map (\n -> { name = n })
```

However the above code doesn't work for me. It appears to return all the topics in descending order.

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/f4dee9abc9117cd3cc5588b6ab31e63d4064020b/Client/app/Home.elm).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "top most occurrences". If you take a list of topics and group them by the "name" property, you get a nested list wherein the topics in the inner list all have the same value for the "name" property. If you map the length function over the outer list you get a list of numbers, each representing the number of occurrences, BUT you lose the topic details. Perhaps you want `List { count : Int, name : String, topics : List Topic }` as the output; the number of topics with the given name, and the corresponding topics themselves.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa the code is using `sortBy`, not `map`.

Comment: Was my answer any use for you

Comment: Hi Simon, I received a shorter solution and used it instead. I didn't test yours but I'll mark it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it would work when I tried it in the Repl

```
module Test exposing (..)

import List as L
import Dict exposing (Dict)


type alias Topic =
    { name : String }


mostCommon : List Topic -> Maybe String
mostCommon lst =
    let
        incrementer : Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
        incrementer mbIdx =
            mbIdx |> Maybe.map ((+) 1) |> Maybe.withDefault 1 |> Just

        go : Topic -> Dict String Int -> Dict String Int
        go t acc =
            Dict.update t.name incrementer acc
    in
        L.foldl go Dict.empty lst
            |> Dict.toList
            |> List.sortBy (Tuple.second >> (*) -1)
            |> L.head
            |> Maybe.map Tuple.first


myMax =
    mostCommon [ Topic "a", Topic "b", Topic "a", Topic "b", Topic "b" ]
```